# What is an elegant way to insert a skip between two paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

From time to time I want to insert a skip between two specific paragraphs (at the end of a thought). My first shot was to simply insert a `\vspace` but the indentation still bothered me.

So what I came up with in the end was a new command:

```
\newcommand{\parspace}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}\noindent}
```

With this I can add it wherever I want and have a break in the text.

However, it doesn't feel very elegant. Is there a better way to perform the same action?

Comment: I don't think this is an inelegant solution. It does exactly what you want and it does it fairly simply. What more could you ask for?

Comment: Do you want it after every paragraph or only ones that you manually specify?

Comment: Only after manually specified paragraphs. Generally I want to keep the preset intendation policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\parspace[1][\bigskip]{\par#1\noindent\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
foo
\parspace
bar
\parspace[\medskip]
baz
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

In some cases it can be useful to space two paragraphs, but it's questionable that the second one hasn't its indentation. So

```
... end of a paragraph.

\medskip % or \bigskip

Start of a new one ...
```

should be sufficient. A paragraph should be unindented only if it has a title or (by stylistic choice) if it immediately follows a title.

Comment: I don’t agree with this assessment. The indentation is to visually distinguish a paragraph from its predecessor. If there’s a clear, big space before it, the indentation becomes redundant and undesirable. This is the general rule that you will find in most books. In fact, I can’t remember a single exception.

Comment: @Konrad: it probably depends on national typographic traditions. Or on bad typography, who knows? :)

Answer (score 4):

If they are two different paragraphs the indention should appear as normal. The indention can be disabled globally by setting the length `\parindent` to 0pt. You can use the `parskip` package to add a separation between all paragraphs.  You can also add more space between two *lines* by using the optional argument of `\\`, e.g. like `\\[\baselineskip]`.

Comment: I didn't want to change the overall layout of my document, I just wanted to insert a space between two specific paragraphs.